# How to properly interpolate a nested property getter in angualr template?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-interpolate

I'm trying to interpolate an nested property getter into angular html template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    {{ myObject.myProps.someProperty1 }} -- Not working
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    {{ myObject.someProperty2 }} -- Working
  </div>
</div>
```

The `myObject.myextendedProps` is a property getter Object typed, but I'm getting an Exception:

> Cannot read property 'someProperty1' of undefined

But I know for sure that `myProps` is not null because when I'm console-logging the `myObject`, I can click on the **Invoke property getter** three dots of the `myProps` property it shows a real value.

My best guess that its a property getter issue. any suggestion solving it?

Comment: Have you tried safe navigation operator?

Comment: Hey @yurzui, no I did not

Comment: Then that's a great case to try it `{{ myObject.myProps?.someProperty1 }}`

Comment: @yurzui, but eventually I'm still want to display the `someProperty1`, this does not resolve my issue

Comment: It will be displayed if it exists

Comment: I looks like it does exist in the chrome console when I click invoke property getter

Comment: Can you please reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: please check the casing and spelling of properties

Comment: Show what myObject contains and is myProps a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can use Elvis operator. The Elvis operator allows you to check for the existence an object before attempting to access its properties in your interpolations

Example  `{{ myObject?.myProps?.someProperty1 }}`

Comment: Hey @Jitendra, this does not resolve my issue. Eventually I'm still want to display the `someProperty1`,

Comment: hey @ShaharShokrani you can also use elvis operator for inner  someProperty1 object. like {{ myObject?.myProps?.someProperty1?.innerProp?.innerProp2 }}

Comment: Elvis operator check if object is available if not available then print blank otherwise display value. It will not display error if object is not found

Answer (score 1):

You may or may not get the error depending on when you are initializing your data.

If you initialize the data i.e. `myObject` before the *view* is initialized then you will not get the error. And it has nothing to do with getter.

so, to stay safe when the view is initialized you can use safe navigation operator ( ? ) like this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    {{ myObject?.myProps?.someProperty1 }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    {{ myObject?.someProperty2 }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, you can use `*ngIf` directive to make sure that you only access properties of `myObject` when `myObject` defined.

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="myObject">
  <div class="col-xs-12" *ngIf="myObject.myProps">
    {{ myObject?.myProps?.someProperty1 }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    {{ myObject?.someProperty2 }}
  </div>
</div>
```

I have created one simple [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbhppe) to understand it better. And you can also read more about Angular component lifecycle here https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks.